# Is String sequence of characters in Java?

Tags: java, character, string-comparison, string-matching

```
String s1 = "a";
System.out.println(s1.equals('a'));
```

Output:

> False

Can anyone please explain me why is it coming `false` even though the string `s1` has only one character `'a'`.

Comment: I fail to see how this result surprises you. The JavaDoc states very clearly "The result is true if and only if the argument [..] is a String object [..]".

Comment: I see it the other way around - it surprises me that you might assume they would be equal :|

Comment: @AashitGarodia Please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why are you getting `false`, which is unexpected for you. First, you need to understand your code

```
s1.equals('a')
```

`s1` is a `String` and `'a'` is `Character`, so you are comparing two different object.

As per **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))** :

> `true` if the given object represents a `String` equivalent to this
>   string, `false` otherwise

Now, come back to `equals` method implementation in **[`String`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)** class.

```
// some more code
if (anObject instanceof String) {
  // code here
  // some more code
 }
 return false;
```

You could see, it is checking if object, which you passed is type of `String` ?? In your case, `No`, it is `Character`. So, you are getting `false` as a result.

Answer (score 2):

One should always consult the specification rather than the implementation (except when there is a reason to suspect that the implementation is wrong, which is not the case here). The specification for `equals` in this case, as quoted in the comment above, is [Class String, method equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) which says:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Since 'a' is not a String the result is false. 'a' is a literal of type `char` but it is boxed to type `Character` because `equals` requires a reference and 'a' is a value.

Answer (score 1):

No. A `char` and a `String` are two different things in Java.

A `char` is exactly a **single** character.

A `String`, on the other hand, is **zero or more** characters. You can have a String of length `0` or `1` or `> 1`. But a character can *only* be of length `1`.

The way you define a character is by using a single quote during the assignment.

```
char first = 'a' // single quotes
```

For a String, you use *double* quotes.

```
String first = "a" // double quotes
```

Comment: OP compares `Character` and `String`, not `char` and `String`.

Comment: Oh. I see. Looks like I made a mistake. But, I think that the logic still holds true even if we use a Character object type.

Comment: Correct, both are different types compared to `String` and an `equals` call should never yield `true`. `'a'` also is a `char` literal, but that will be boxed for the `equals` call, because there is no overloaded version of that method, which accepts a primitive type. Thus OP actually compares `Character` to `String`. But you're right, both types are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are used for literal `char`, double quotes for literal `String`.
Further if you will look at the equals method in String class, it is overridden as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
      if (this == anObject) {
          return true;
      }
      if (anObject instanceof String) {
          String anotherString = (String)anObject;
          int n = count;
          if (n == anotherString.count) {
              char v1[] = value;
              char v2[] = anotherString.value;
              int i = offset;
              int j = anotherString.offset;
              while (n-- != 0) {
                  if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                      return false;
              }
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Neither, char is an instance of String class nor they are referencing same object on heap.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a difference between a single quote `''` and double quote `""`

Comment: I'm purposely doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, you can see how `String.equals()` implemented. The method checks the parameter is instance of `String` and return false if the parameter is not a `String`.